# How to fix parse-error with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, list, lighttpd, raspberry-pi3

I tried to install `Lighttpd`, but I got this error:

> Reading package lists... Error!
>   E: Unable to parse package file
>   /var/lib/dpkg/status (1) E: The package lists or status file could not
>   be parsed or opened.

So, I've searched on the internet and tried to remove and reload the package lists:

> @rasp:~ $ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf removed
>   '/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.raspberrypi.org_debian_dists_jessie_InRelease'
>   removed
>   '/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.raspberrypi.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-armhf_Packages'
>   removed
>   '/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.raspberrypi.org_debian_dists_jessie_ui_binary-armhf_Packages'
>   removed '/var/lib/apt/lists/lock' removed
>   '/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_jessie_contrib_binary-armhf_Packages'
>   removed
>   '/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_jessie_InRelease'
>   removed
>   '/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_jessie_main_binary-armhf_Packages'
>   removed
>   '/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_jessie_non-free_binary-armhf_Packages'
>   removed
>   '/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_jessie_rpi_binary-armhf_Packages'
>   rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': Is a directory
>   pi@rasp:~ $ sudo apt-get clean pi@rasp:~ $ sudo
>   apt-get update Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease
>   [13.2 kB] Get:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
>   [14.9 kB] Get:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf
>   Packages [144 kB] Get:4 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main
>   armhf Packages [8980 kB] Get:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.org
>   jessie/ui armhf Packages [8966 B]        Ign
>   http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en
>   Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en Get:6
>   http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages [37.5
>   kB] Get:7 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf
>   Packages [70.3 kB] Get:8 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi
>   armhf Packages [1356 B]     Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org
>   jessie/contrib Translation-en            Ign
>   http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en
>   Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en 
>   Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
>   Fetched 9271 kB in 1min 36s (95.8 kB/s)
>   Reading package lists... Error! E: Unable to parse package file
>   /var/lib/dpkg/status (1) E: The package lists or status file could not
>   be parsed or opened.

How to fix this error? Updating the lists, like recommended in many forums, doesn't work, seeing the quote above.

Comment: why you touch apt files when error is in dpkg files?
If `/var/lib/dpkg/status` is corrupted look `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old` it is backup copy for `/var/lib/dpkg/status`

Answer (score 2):

you have to replace the status file

```
cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

if that doesn't help, because status-old is corrupted as well get the initial status file from backups

```
cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

then run apt-get update